# wp_query custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I dont know if I just can t see the forrest for the tress, but I need some help. I have a custom post type "business" with 2 related custom taxonomies, business_category and business_tags. On the custom archive template I have a custom search form:

```
<form class="search-form" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="search-input"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="screen-reader-text">Search icons</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="wego_business" />
            <input type="search" class="form-control search-field" placeholder="Search the Directory" value="" name="s" id="s">
        </div>
    </form>
```

This then display on a custom search template. I can not get results for the business_tags

```
global $wp_query;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$tag = get_search_query();
$args = array (
    's'                     => $s,
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'orderby'               => 'name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'business_tags',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $tag,
        ),
    ),
    'paged'                 => $paged
);
```

AM I missing something obvious?

Here is the cpt creation:

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Business', 'Post Type General Name', 'wego_fran' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Business', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'wego_fran' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Business:', 'wego_fran' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'wego_fran' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'wego_fran' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'wego_fran' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Business', 'wego_fran' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'business_category', 'business_tags' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 20,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-admin-home',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'business' ),
);
register_post_type( 'wego_business', $args );

<?php
global $wp_query;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$tag = get_search_query();
$args = array (
    'post_type'             => 'wego_business',
    's'                     => $s,
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'orderby'               => 'name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'business_tags',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $tag,
        ),
    ),
    'paged'                 => $paged
);

// The Query
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$count = $wp_query->found_posts;
```

?>

the custom search template is search-wego_business.php using the above query

Comment: First: what is the name of your custom search template? Are you *sure* that it's loading that template? (Your form is going to trigger the built-in / default "WordPress search").  Second, your tax query seems to be looking for a "slug" - are you entering the "slug" into your search input? Third - as the answer below points out - you don't have the `post_type` parameter, so your args are going to by default query only `posts`.  Lastly, you haven't included the code that runs your query, or that outputs the results, so we can only assume you are confident the query is executing properly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're missing the `post_type` field and you can also search inside the `name` field. A refactor would look like:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'business',
    's'                     => $s,
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'orderby'               => 'name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'business_tags',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $tag,
        ),
    ),
    'paged' => $paged
);
```

Else, I would need more details - like: your taxonomy and custom post type declaration and the full source of your archive (at least the part that builds the search query).

Comment: From the OP's code, you can see the post type should be `wego_business`, not `business`

Comment: Yeah @cale_b - in description OP says `business`, in form name attr. it's `wego_business` - perhaps full code will help us to check it better! :)